# I cant access a class I defined from the main loop?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, file-structure

I have an extremely simple piece of code where I am calling a method that I defined, and it wont run because it says I haven't defined the method?

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
go(7,3);
  }
```

}
/// in a separate file named go.java -->

```
 class go{
public static int go(int x, int y){
 if(x <= 1)
     return y;
  else
      return go(x - 1, y) + y;
```

}
}

Comment: Please provide a [mre], this does not look like all of your relevant code. Maybe that is the problem, but that must be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, use the class name `go` to identify the class containing the method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    go.go(7,3);
}
```

**or** `static import` it like

```
import static go.go;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        go(7,3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, Class name should start with upper case, your another class should be *Go.java* , to access static method
Refer Class name that is **Go.go(7,3);**